# bash script loop through two variables in lock step

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a bash script that loops through two variables:

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in sd fd dir && j in storage file director
 do
   echo "restarting bacula $j daemon"
   /sbin/service bacula-$i restart
   echo
done
```

The code above is obviously wrong. But I want i & j to move in lock step with one another. Can someone help me with a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
a=(sd fd dir)
b=(storage file director)
for k in "${!a[@]}"
do
   echo "restarting bacula ${b[k]} daemon"
   /sbin/service "bacula-${a[k]}" restart
   echo
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrays and a manual loop.

```
a=(sd fd dir)
b=(storage file director)

for ((i = 0; i <= ${#a}; i++)); do
    echo "restarting bacula ${b[i]} daemon"
    /sbin/service "bacula-${a[i]}" restart
done
```